# where exactly i shlould place INDIRECT() in excel?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a named range by name 'AlgeriaBchar'.  (Algeria-> countryname and Bchar-> statename)
I use constraint on city dropdown as content in country dropdown + state dropdown (i.e. E7 + F7).
But as we can see in img staename is 'Béchar' which i need to remove char 'é' as it doesnt fit in a-z, A-Z, 0-9.
I also need to remove any blank spaces, hiphns, square brackets, apostrophy marks in country and state dropdown contents

[image]

1. I m not getting in which sequence I should put these fucntions to get it to 'AlgeriaBchar'
   For better understanding I provided indentation to data validation fucntion in excel.
   I'll be putting this fucntion in city dropdown's validaity constraint.
2. I may need to evaluate each character in a string which will need for loop. MID( E7, 1 ,1 ) gives me only 1st chracter. How can I loop it till the length of the string. 
   can anyone suggest me.

   =IF(
   NOT( 
       AND( CODE( MID( E7, 1 ,1 ) ) >=65 , CODE( MID( E7, 1 ,1 ) ) <=90 )
   )
   AND(
       NOT(
           AND( CODE( MID( E7, 1 ,1 ) ) >=97 , CODE( MID( E7, 1 ,1 ) ) <=122 ) 
       )
   )
   AND(
       NOT(
           AND( CODE( MID( E7, 1 ,1 ) ) >=48 , CODE( MID( E7, 1 ,1 ) ) <=57 )
       )

   )
   , SUBSTITUTE( E7, MID( E7, 1 ,1 ), "" ) ,""
   )

INDIRECT(
    SUBSTITUTE(
        SUBSTITUTE(
            SUBSTITUTE(
                SUBSTITUTE(
                    SUBSTITUTE(UPPER($E$7)," ","")
                ,"-","")
            ,"'","")
        ,"[","")
    ,"]","") 
)
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use a macro for that. Consider this one (based on this article from [extendoffice.com](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/707-excel-replace-accented-characters.html))

1) Hold down the Alt + F11 keys in Excel, and it opens the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications window.

2) Click Insert > Module, and paste the following macro in the Module Window.

```
Function StripAccent(thestring As String)

Dim A As String * 1
Dim B As String * 1
Dim i As Integer

Const AccChars = "ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ-[]' "

For i = 1 To Len(AccChars)

     A = Mid(AccChars, i, 1)

     thestring = Replace(thestring, A, "")

Next

StripAccent = thestring

End Function


Function TrimmedConcat(A As String, B As String)

    TrimmedConcat = StripAccent(A) & StripAccent(B)

End Function
```

Then in your document, click in a cell, and use TrimmedConcat as if it was a normal function, selecting the country name as the first argument and the city name as the second.

In your example `=TrimmedConcat(E7,F7)`

I hope that helps!

Comment: Hi.. thank you so much for your help. It really works. But the thing is I need to generate the excel sheet using Apache POI + java. and I found that Apache POI doesnt provide support for inserting macro. So i Cant insert it. But your code helped me. I manually checked chracters against set as you provided 'AccChars'. And it worked.!! thank you so much again.